# How can I set scip options using pyomo?

Tags: pyomo, scip

I am trying to set parameter values for solving a pyomo model using SCIP. When I run

```
opt = SolverFactory('scipampl')
solver_message = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
```

SCIP solves the model mich means that the setup of scipampl has worked. Yet I'm not sure what's the right way to add options. I found that this was adressed [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/48) before and seems to have been integrated in [this](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/commit/b0ce4815cb6eb94c72972c3297f80fbe0eb7548b) git commit.

I have tried setting options via

```
opt.options['limits/time'] = 100
```

which results in the error

```
.../scipoptsuite-6.0.2/scip/src/scip/paramset.c:2569] ERROR: cannot open file <limits/time=100> for reading
limits/time=100: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions how to set SCIP options properly in pyomo?

Edit:
While I would still be interested in how passing SCIP-options via pyomo is intended, I found a workaround which worked for me.
I set options via the SCIP interactive shell and saved the file (also via shell) as scip.set at the place from which the python script is run.

Comment: if I understand the linked pyomo issue correctly then adding a settings file is what you should do (as you said in your edit). I am not familiar with pyomo, however, just with scip.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Leon. The git issue I linked has the following comment:

"If SCIP doesn't accept command-line options like other solvers compiled against ASL, we should consider writing this file for the user (...)" and that's what seems to have been done in the git commit I linked. 

So it should work from within Python/Pyomo, but I can't see how.

Comment: Try directly: solver_message = opt.solve(model, options={'limits/time':100}, tee=True)